# Конвертнуть строку вида "7.2E-05" в decimal C#

Tags: c#

Конвертнуть строку вида "7.2E-05" в decimal C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string from = "7.2E-05";
double f = double.Parse(from.Replace('.',','));
decimal d =(decimal)f;
```

Или если совместить:

```
decimal d = (decimal)double.Parse("7.2E-05".Replace('.',','));
```

Comment: Replace('.',',') - не очень хорошо, разделитель парсер берёт из региональных настроек. Лучше так: <br>Replace('.', Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator)

Comment: Да, верно. тогда уж и запятую заменять:)

Comment: @MaxXx1313, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.